# Eclipse Logcat Displays loads of errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, logcat

I'm developing an android app,Now the problem is when I run this app in emulator It works fine but Logcat displays a lot of errors so I'm not sure what could be the problem ? Is it an emulator problem ? any comments will be much appreciated

Logcat

```
 04-27 19:40:50.700: E/vinput-seamless(91): found PS2 device
04-27 19:40:50.700: E/vinput-seamless(91): found seamless mouse device
04-27 19:40:52.260: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -N bw_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.260: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -N bw_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.260: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j bw_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.268: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j bw_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.280: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -N idletimer_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.280: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -N idletimer_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.280: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j idletimer_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.280: E/Netd(96): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j idletimer_raw_PREROUTING 
04-27 19:40:52.868: E/setdpi(324): Setting DPI to 240
04-27 19:40:52.868: E/SurfaceFlinger(99): hwcomposer module not found
04-27 19:40:52.896: E/cutils-trace(99): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-27 19:40:54.700: E/BandwidthController(96): runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/iptables -t raw -A bw_raw_PREROUTING -m owner --socket-exists
04-27 19:40:54.700: E/BandwidthController(96): runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -A bw_raw_PREROUTING -m owner --socket-exists
04-27 19:40:54.836: E/cutils-trace(343): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-27 19:40:56.572: E/MonoPipe(102): Failed to fetch local time frequency when constructing a MonoPipe (res = -32).  getNextWriteTimestamp calls will be non-functional
04-27 19:40:59.140: E/cutils-trace(100): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-27 19:41:09.868: E/libsuspend(459): Error opening /sys/power/autosleep: No such file or directory
04-27 19:41:09.868: E/libsuspend(459): Error opening /sys/power/wakeup_count: Permission denied
04-27 19:41:09.868: E/libsuspend(459): failed to initialize autosuspend
04-27 19:41:09.948: E/WVMExtractor(102): Failed to open libwvm.so
04-27 19:41:09.952: E/cutils-trace(102): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-27 19:41:10.072: E/EventHub(459): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse3, Not a typewriter
04-27 19:41:10.084: E/EventHub(459): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse2, Not a typewriter
04-27 19:41:10.104: E/EventHub(459): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse1, Not a typewriter
04-27 19:41:10.172: E/EventHub(459): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
04-27 19:41:10.224: E/EventHub(459): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
04-27 19:41:10.332: E/MobileDataStateTracker(459): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
04-27 19:41:10.332: E/MobileDataStateTracker(459): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
04-27 19:41:10.560: E/libsuspend(459): Error opening /sys/power/autosleep: No such file or directory
04-27 19:41:10.560: E/libsuspend(459): Error opening /sys/power/wakeup_count: Permission denied
04-27 19:41:10.560: E/libsuspend(459): failed to initialize autosuspend
04-27 19:41:11.260: E/BandwidthController(96): runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/iptables -t raw -A bw_raw_PREROUTING -m owner --socket-exists
04-27 19:41:11.264: E/BandwidthController(96): runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=768 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -t raw -A bw_raw_PREROUTING -m owner --socket-exists
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459): problem enabling bandwidth controls
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459): com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector$NativeDaemonFailureException: command '1 bandwidth enable' failed with '400 1 Bandwidth command failed'
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:382)
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.executeForList(NativeDaemonConnector.java:318)
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:283)
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.prepareNativeDaemon(NetworkManagementService.java:335)
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.systemReady(NetworkManagementService.java:211)
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.ServerThread$3.run(SystemServer.java:887)
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:8148)
04-27 19:41:11.264: A/NetworkManagementService(459):    at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:866)
04-27 19:41:11.264: E/NetdConnector(459): NDC Command {1 bandwidth enable} took too long (651ms)
04-27 19:41:11.272: E/WifiStateMachine(459): Failed to reload STA firmware java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: command '2 softap fwreload eth1 STA' failed with '501 2 SoftAP command has failed'
04-27 19:41:11.276: E/Netd(96): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/use_tempaddr: No such file or directory
04-27 19:41:11.276: E/WifiStateMachine(459): Unable to change interface settings: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '5 interface ipv6privacyextensions eth1 enable' failed with '400 5 Failed to set ipv6 privacy extensions (No such file or directory)'
04-27 19:41:11.360: E/WifiHW(459): Unable to open connection to supplicant on "eth1": No such file or directory
04-27 19:41:11.476: E/OpenGLRenderer(538): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-27 19:41:11.508: E/OpenGLRenderer(538): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-27 19:41:12.116: E/LocationManagerService(459): no geocoder provider found
04-27 19:41:12.124: E/LocationManagerService(459): no geofence provider found
04-27 19:41:12.364: E/WifiConfigStore(459): Error parsing configurationjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-27 19:41:12.368: E/GpsLocationProvider(459): no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
04-27 19:41:12.404: E/WifiStateMachine(459): Failed to set frequency band 0
04-27 19:41:12.456: E/GpsLocationProvider(459): no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
04-27 19:41:15.316: E/jdwp(809): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-27 19:41:15.784: E/BluetoothPhoneService(671): Could not get a handle on Connection object for the call
04-27 19:41:15.980: E/OpenGLRenderer(679): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-27 19:41:15.996: E/OpenGLRenderer(679): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-27 19:41:18.388: E/bt-btif(864): /data/misc/bluedroid/ does not exist, need provision
04-27 19:41:18.420: E/bt-btif(864): ## btif_config_get assert section && *section && key && *key && name && *name && bytes && type failed at line:182 ##
04-27 19:41:18.420: E/bt-btif(864): btif_config_save_file failed
04-27 19:41:18.424: E/bt-btif(864): btif_config_save_file failed
04-27 19:41:18.456: E/bt-btif(864): btif_enable_service: current services:0x40
04-27 19:41:18.468: E/bt-btif(864): btif_enable_service: current services:0x40040
04-27 19:41:18.500: E/bt-btif(864): btif_enable_service: current services:0x140040
04-27 19:41:18.608: E/bt_hw(864): !!! Failed to load libbt-vendor.so !!!
04-27 19:41:18.608: E/bt_hci_bdroid(864): vendor lib is missing!
04-27 19:41:18.608: E/bt_hci_bdroid(864): vendor lib is missing!
04-27 19:41:18.616: E/bt_userial(864): userial_open: missing vendor lib interface !!!
04-27 19:41:18.616: E/bt_userial(864): userial_open: unable to open UART port
04-27 19:41:19.656: E/SQLiteLog(972): (1) no such table: Account
04-27 19:41:21.440: E/BluetoothManagerService(459): waitForOnOff time out
04-27 19:41:21.616: E/bt-btif(864): ...preload_wait_timeout (retried:0/max-retry:0)...
04-27 19:41:21.616: E/bt_hci_bdroid(864): vendor lib is missing!
04-27 19:41:21.616: E/BluetoothAdapterState(864): Error enabling Bluetooth - hardware init failed
04-27 19:41:21.616: E/bt-btif(864): btif_disable_service: Current Services:0x140000
04-27 19:41:21.620: E/bt-btif(864): btif_disable_service: Current Services:0x100000
04-27 19:41:21.628: E/bt-btif(864): btif_disable_service: Current Services:0x100000
04-27 19:43:54.869: E/OpenGLRenderer(1275): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-27 19:43:54.873: E/OpenGLRenderer(1275): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all Logcat messages are yours. Each entry has a TAG field and an application field. Use filters to hide log output that doesn't belong to you.

About Logcat: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html and https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Answer (score 0):

Logcat usually display all error, warnings, exception, debug messages, etc at same time from all running applications.

Try adding some TAG specific to your application and filter it in logcat.